# How to show custom contact fields for campaign members' page on the campaigns tab?

Tags: contact, campaign

I would like to know how to show custom contact fields for campaign members' page on the campaigns tab?

Answer (score 2):

You can create formula fields on the `Campaign Member` object (Setup->Customize->Campaigns->Campaign Members->Fields) and reference your contact's custom fields via the Contact lookup field on the Campaign Member object. Ex: `Contact.Custom_Field__c.`

Then by editing the layout of the campaign, navigate to the related list of the Campaign Members and click the related list properties button (wrench icon). There you can add your formula field that references the contact field and re-arrange the columns in the related list.